# What does a pair of numbers in parentheses mean as a focal length value in metadata?

Tags: metadata, focal-length

I have extracted the metadata from an image. One of the values was:

```
FocalLength: (3680, 1000)
```

How can we read the above value?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Values in [Exif metadata](http://www.cipa.jp/std/documents/e/DC-008-2012_E.pdf) can be stored as various data types, including ASCII text strings, "short" or "long" integers, or "rationals". A short integer is stored in two bytes; a long integer takes four bytes. A "rational" is:

> Two  LONGs.  The  first  LONG  is  the  numerator  and  the  second  LONG expresses the denominator.

That is,`FocalLength: (3680, 1000)` means 3680 / 1000, or 3.68. (Elsewhere in the spec, this is defined to be in millimeters.) For whatever reason, whatever program you are looking at this with is just showing you the two "long" values rather than doing the math for you.

It's also incredibly important to note that hundredths of a millimeter is almost certainly excess precision. For practical use, call this 3.7mm or 4mm.

Comment: Why don't we ever see a prime number as the denominator in such a string? ;-)

Comment: @MichaelClark It's weird, yeah. In fact, why not just use ***1*** in most cases? My Pentax and Fujifilm cameras use 100 in the denominator. Files I have from a Nikon use 10, and those from my smartphone use 1000. A couple of iPhone files I have use 20 (iPhone 5) and 25 (iPhone 5s).

Comment: If this is from a phone camera, 3.68 might be excess precision, but 3.7 isn't: the tiny sensor means the overall range of even a long zoom lens isn't very large.

Comment: @Mark The smaller the sensor the wider the range between a specific number of millimeters. A 1/3" sensor presents the same FoV at 3.7mm as a FF camera at 27mm. at 4mm focal length it has the same FoV as a FF camera at 29mm. To get a 1200mm/FF FoV one only needs a 165mm lens with a 1/3" sensor. Perhaps you meant "... the tiny sensor means the overall *size* (or *focal length*) of a long telephoto lens isn't very large?"

Comment: @MichaelClark - I think what he's saying is that when sensors and respective FLs become tiny, mm becomes an increasingly coarse unit, possibly not suitable for some purposes when rounded...

Comment: @junkyardsparkle Yeah, I got that, but usually *range* means *reach* when talking about telephoto lenses. A specific focal length has much greater *reach* or *range* when used with a small sensor than when used with a larger one.

Comment: @MichaelClark Hmmm. I just read "range" in its sense of "degree of variation" from context. Words are funny. :)

Comment: Even then, the *range* in terms of difference in FOV would be *greater* for a small sensor camera, but he says it isn't very large. Maybe he means to say *the overall focal length range of even a wide ratio zoom lens isn't very large?"

Comment: I read it as "range *in millimeters*"...

Comment: It's true that millimeters are a course unit. My point is that I doubt the focal length given is *accurate* to that precision, at least not for any practical purpose like measuring things, as people tend to come here wanting to do.